# Build path error in the attempt of implementing the Facebook Login

Tags: eclipse, facebook-login, facebook-android-sdk, buildpath

I'm trying to implement the Facebook login in my app using Eclipse, so I started off by going through the tutorials on Facebook Developers. However, I'm encountering an error in my build path, so any help would be appreciated.

In the Android Dependencies, it states that 'facebooksdk.jar - "Directory\facebook-android-sdk-3.0.1.b\bin (missing)"'

If there's any info that I left out that might be important, let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: Already fixed it, just gotta wait a few more hours to self-answer and close the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, managed to get it working.  Simply deleted the project that was in the Build Path's Projects tab, and imported it again, but this time, I only imported the *facebook* folder instead of the entire facebook-android-sdk-3.0.1.b folder, and updated the project build path.

Answer (score 1):

The way I resolved the android dependency issue was to right click on the FacebookSDK project, go to Properties>Android and check Google APIs for the Build Target and check isLibrary below that.  After pressing OK, I went to Project>Clean... and cleaned all projects.  After that, give eclipse a few seconds, and it should update all the projects to remove the build errors.

Comment: after a few hours of frustration your answer hit the damn spot man!